# Program wont access login and password stored as a .txt and allow login of registered use with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, authentication, tkinter

I am trying to create a basic login system for a tkinter project. I am just learning python and tkinter. On another part of the code a registration system creates a file within the project folder that I can see and have verified that the username and password are present are registering. However, I just can't seem to figure out why it always tells me that the User is not found and I am unable to login. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import random
import time
import os
def main():
    main_screen()
#creates our GUI and names it
def main_screen():
    global E1
    global E2
    global root
    global uname
    global passw
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.title("Final Project")
    root.geometry('500x500')
    uname = StringVar()
    passw = StringVar()
#create labels and locations
    title = tkinter.Label(root, text="My First Login", font=("Times New Roman", 50)).grid(column=0,    row=0, columnspan=4)
    uname_lab = tkinter.Label(root, text="Username", font=("Times New Roman",20)).grid(column=0, row=1)
    passw_lab = tkinter.Label(root, text="Password", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=0, row=2)
#creates entry spaces for uname and passw
    E1=tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=uname).grid(column=1, row=1)
    E2=tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=passw).grid(column=1, row=2)
#submit button creation
    submit_button=tkinter.Button(root, text="Submit",bg= "black", fg = "white", command=    login_verify).grid(column=2, row=2)
    regis_button=tkinter.Button(root, text="Register Now", bg= "Black", fg="white", command= register).grid(column=0, row=3)
    root.mainloop()
def register_user():
    username_info = uname1.get()
    password_info = passw1.get()
    file = open(username_info + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()
    tkinter.Label(regscreen, text="You have registered", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=3, row=4)
def login_verify ():
    global uname_verify
    global passw_verify
    uname_verify=StringVar()
    passw_verify=StringVar()
    uname_verify = uname.get()
    passw_verify = passw.get()
    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if uname_verify in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(uname,"r")
        verify =file1.read().splitlines()
        if passw in verify:
            print('Login Success')
        else:
            print("Password not recognized")
    else:
        print("user not found")
def register():
    global regscreen
    global uname1
    global passw1
    global regis_uname
    global regis_passw

    #creates the registration screen
    regscreen= Toplevel(root)
    regscreen.title("Register")
    regscreen.geometry("500x500")
#declares what type of variable the username and password are
    uname1 = StringVar()
    passw1 = StringVar()
#places labels for refistration screen
    regis_title = tkinter.Label(regscreen, text="Please register.", font=("Times New Roman", 50)).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4)
    regist_uname = tkinter.Label(regscreen, text="Username", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=0, row=1)
    regist_passw = tkinter.Label(regscreen,text="Password", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=0, row=2)
#creates entries for registration screen
    E3 = tkinter.Entry(regscreen, textvariable=uname1).grid(column=1, row=1)
    E4 = tkinter.Entry(regscreen, textvariable=passw1).grid(column=1, row=2)
#creates submit button for registration page
    submit_button1 = tkinter.Button(regscreen, text="Submit", bg="black", fg="white",  command=register_user).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=EW)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Since you've isolated the problem to reading the passwords file, I would recommend taking a closer look at your `login_verify` function and how you've configured your submit button. Moreover, you might consider re-phrasing this question with a more minimal example. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.)

Answer (score 0):

Here. I reworked your code, and the main issue was the assigning of the `textvariable`. Also, use `.grid()` in a seperate line. This way, you can use `E1.get()` without getting an error.

Here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import random
import time
import os
def main():
    main_screen()
#creates our GUI and names it
def main_screen():
    global E1
    global E2
    global root
    global uname
    global passw
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.title("Final Project")
    root.geometry('500x500')
#create labels and locations
    title = tkinter.Label(root, text="My First Login", font=("Times New Roman", 50)).grid(column=0,    row=0, columnspan=4)
    uname_lab = tkinter.Label(root, text="Username", font=("Times New Roman",20)).grid(column=0, row=1)
    passw_lab = tkinter.Label(root, text="Password", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=0, row=2)
#creates entry spaces for uname and passw
    E1=tkinter.Entry(root)
    E1.grid(column=1, row=1)
    E2=tkinter.Entry(root, show = "*")
    E2.grid(column=1, row=2)
#submit button creation
    submit_button=tkinter.Button(root, text="Submit",bg= "black", fg = "white", command=    login_verify).grid(column=2, row=2)
    regis_button=tkinter.Button(root, text="Register Now", bg= "Black", fg="white", command= register).grid(column=0, row=3)
    root.mainloop()
def register_user():
    username_info = uname1.get()
    password_info = passw1.get()
    file = open(username_info + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()
    tkinter.Label(regscreen, text="You have registered", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=3, row=4)
def login_verify ():
    global uname_verify
    global passw_verify

    uname_verify = E1.get() + ".txt"
    passw_verify = E2.get()
    list_of_files = os.listdir()

    if uname_verify in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(uname_verify, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if E2.get() in verify:
            print('Login Success')
        else:
            print("Password not recognized")
    else:
        print("user not found")
def register():
    global regscreen
    global uname1
    global passw1
    global regis_uname
    global regis_passw

    #creates the registration screen
    regscreen= Toplevel(root)
    regscreen.title("Register")
    regscreen.geometry("500x500")
#declares what type of variable the username and password are
    uname1 = StringVar()
    passw1 = StringVar()
#places labels for refistration screen
    regis_title = tkinter.Label(regscreen, text="Please register.", font=("Times New Roman", 50)).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4)
    regist_uname = tkinter.Label(regscreen, text="Username", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=0, row=1)
    regist_passw = tkinter.Label(regscreen,text="Password", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=0, row=2)
#creates entries for registration screen
    E3 = tkinter.Entry(regscreen, textvariable=uname1, show = "*").grid(column=1, row=1)
    E4 = tkinter.Entry(regscreen, textvariable=passw1, show = "*").grid(column=1, row=2)
#creates submit button for registration page
    submit_button1 = tkinter.Button(regscreen, text="Submit", bg="black", fg="white",  command=register_user).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=EW)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That makes so much more sense the way that you did that. Thank you!

Comment: @jgreene2 If it worked, would you mind upvoting it? Thanks!